# Haskell Data.Void: undefined turns into infinite loop

Tags: haskell, void

I noticed one thing about the `Void` type in the haskell `Data.Void` module, which is weird and I'd very much like to know why it is the way it is.
Undefined is supposed to be a value that exists for every type (in my understanding), and

```
undefined :: Type
```

is supposed to yield

```
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

which works for every data type I have tried, except for `Void`.
`undefined :: Void` does not terminate at all, same for `absurd undefined`.
Now I don't think that's really much of an issue since `Void` represents a value that is not going to happen anyway, but I would still like to know what causes this behavior.

Comment: I can't replicate this on GHCi 7.10.1 with `void` 0.7.

Comment: Nor can I on 7.8.3 with void 0.6.1. (Still holding out for the next HP - any day now...) Anyway, I suspect this will be *highly* dependent on exactly what versions you are invoking, with which (optimization esp.) options, and how you are running it.

Comment: I am running ghci on version 7.6.3. But good to know.

Comment: Might be a weird `Show Void` instance?

Comment: @melpomene that shouldn't be it since `absurd` doesn't try to show a `Void`

Comment: I am also using void 0.7. by the way.

Comment: Oh also in very recent GHCs `Data.Void` is a `base` module, with a different definition but most of the same features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a bit more investigation, I think I understand how this can happen, and how it depends on optimization choices by GHC.  In `void-0.7`, we have the following relevant definitions:

```
newtype Void = Void Void

absurd :: Void -> a
absurd a = a `seq` spin a where
   spin (Void b) = spin b

instance Show Void where
  showsPrec _ = absurd
```

Note that the `Show` instance delegates to `absurd`, which explains why `undefined :: Void` in GHCi gives the same result as `absurd undefined`.

Now looking at the definition of `absurd a`, it uses `seq` to "ensure" that `a` is actually evaluated, so you would think that should trigger the `undefined` exception. However, subtly `seq` doesn't actually work that way. `` a `seq` b `` only guarantees that *both* `a` and `b` will be evaluated before the whole expression returns, but *not* in which order.  It is entirely up to the choice of the implementation which part is evaluated first.

This means that `GHC` is free to either evaluate the `a` first, triggering the exception; or else to evaluate `spin a` first.  If it evaluates `spin a` first, then you get an infinite loop, because the `Void` constructor is a `newtype` constructor, and by design, unwrapping those doesn't actually evaluate anything.

So therefore, by the semantics of `seq`, both options are actually equally legal Haskell behavior.

As a final note, the [exception semantics in GHC](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/imprecise-exn.htm) have been defined as explicitly nondeterministic:  If an expression could give bottom in several different ways, GHC can choose any of them.  Since the only way to *distinguish* different bottoms is in `IO`, this is considered acceptable.

Comment: This smells like a good reason to change the definition of absurd, probably to use (or reimplement) `pseq`. It's much better to get an exception than an infinite loop.

Comment: @dfeuer Well the [new definition in `base`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Data.Void.html#absurd) is entirely different, using the empty case block feature, so no infinite loop should be involved.

Comment: @dfeuer Oh and the `void` package has been written with a policy of being Haskell 98 compatible, so it couldn't use `pseq` or the new empty datatype features.